# Database is too old and required upgrade for Service Application database

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, service-application

I'm facing the error "Database is too old and required upgrade" in Central Admin for StateService and SecureStoreService database, but when I ran "Get-SPContentDatabase" it shows NeedsUpgrade property "False" for the above two databases.Can anyone helps to fix this issue and how to upgrade these database.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the Config Wizard on all farm members. Since those databases aren't content databases, they're upgraded in the global upgrade session only.

Comment: this happens after installing the patches. I have checked the UpgradeLog it was skipping the "SecureStoreService" application database

Comment: After installing patches you need to run the Config Wizard. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/upgrade-and-update/deploy-updates-for-sharepoint-server-2016

Comment: Yes!! we ran Configuration Wizard on all servers in this farm."Database is too old and required upgrade" status only showing for this two database all other service application DB looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the command below in SharePoint management Shell:

```
Psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -force
```

If the issue still exists, follow the blog to check if there is any additional database that the services used:

[Database is too old upgrade is required](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/balasm/database-is-too-old-upgrade-is-required)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the farm account had to be db owner on the databases